# Convert massive MySQL dump file to CSV

Tags: mysql, bash, sed, awk

I tryed something like this

```
awk -F " " '{if($1=="INSERT"){print $5}}' input.sql | \
    sed -e "s/^(//g" -e "s/),(/\n/g" -e "s/['\"]//g" \
        -e "s/);$//g" -e "s/,/;/g" > output.txt
```

But I find it slow and unoptimized

A MySQL dump file looks like the following

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable{
    data_1,
    data_2
};

INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES ('data_1','data_2'),...,('data_1','data_2');
INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES ('data_1','data_2'),...,('data_1','data_2');
...
INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES ('data_1','data_2'),...,('data_1','data_2');
```

My goal is to get a file with the following result (and without ' or " to enclose fields):

```
data_1,data_2
data_1,data_2
...
data_1,data_2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean that `data_1` is like `"some data"` with double or single quotes?

Comment: Or do you mean `data_1, data_2` is like `'data_1, data_2'`?

Comment: Sry I edited, my `...`, must have misleaded you... I need the N (data_1,data_2) couples present on each line, not only the first one... My mistake

Comment: Ok, see my update.. Does that work for you?

Comment: Will there always be single quotes around each couple? Like `('abc,def')`?

Comment: Can there be commas within each data element? Like `('abc,xf','gg')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
gawk '/^INSERT/ {
    match ($0,/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/,a)
    print a[1]
}' input.sql
```

*** Update ***

After reading the question again, maybe this is more what you want:

```
/^INSERT/ {
    line=$0
    while (match (line,/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/,a)) {
        cur=a[1]
        sub(/^['"]/,"",cur)
        sub(/['"]$/,"",cur)
        print cur
        line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

*** Update 2 ***

Based on the last update of the question, here is a new version:

```
/^INSERT/ {
    line=$0
    while (match (line,/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/,a)) {
        line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        match(a[1],/'([^']*)','([^']*)'/,b)
        print b[1]
        print b[2]
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to execute it on a single line:
gawk '/^INSERT/ {line=$0;while (match (line,/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/,a)){;cur=a[1];sub(/^[\'"]/,"",cur);sub(/[\'"]$/,"",cur);print cur;line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}' input.sql
I get the following: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
Probably some quotes should be escaped?

Comment: @Syffys Ok..Try to put the awk script in a file `f.awk`, then execute `awk -f f.awk input.sql`..

Comment: Thanks, It's indeed working now! However, it seems to be very much slower than my previous command...

Comment: @Syffys Yes you are right, it is about half as slow as your original version. I will try to make a faster one..

Comment: @Syffys I tried to make it faster, but I failed.. I guess the reason is either `substr` or `match` or both in combination..

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n "/.*INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES (\([^)]*\)).*/ {
   s/.*INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES \(.*\);/\1/
   s/(\([^)]*\)),*/\\1\\
/g
   s/'//g
   s/\\n$//
   p
   }" input.sql > output.sql
```

based on your (new) sample

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I must have misleaded you with my `...`, I updated my sample. Thanks!